# NHibernate - Only persist changes when a save/update call is made

Tags: nhibernate

NHibernate auto saves any changes made to an object regardless of whether you make a session.save/update call or not when committing a transaction. EG.

```
session.BeginTransaction();

User user = repos.getUser("tony");

user.Age = 34

transaction.Commit();
```

Age is updated. This can be annoying when you want to get an object from the DB and make some changes without those changes being saved. You can session.evict the object, but then you lose the ability to load proxies.

Is there a way to get NHibernate to only persist changes if a save/update call is made?

Update:

Thanks for responses, no one told me how to do it (and it may not be possible) so I am going to leave it unanswered.

You should wrap all db calls in a transaction and commit that transaction to close it.

I am doing this because there is complex sorting I do of the results that isn't really possible via SQL/NHibernate. Unfortunately NHibernate assumes I want to save this new order back to the DB.

My workaround is to add a property to my transaction attribute [Transaction(onlyread = true)] which causes it to use FlushMode.Never

I think for future work I will just make sure to only make changes that I want to persist. Pity there isn't the option to only save when you explicitly call it.

Comment: what happens if you put your transaction.commit before user.Age=34?

Comment: Well, you don't HAVE to open a transaction...

Comment: Why do you want to make changes to an entity and not persist them? Perhaps the answer is in changing the design rather than the way NHibernate works.

Comment: @g So that you can you can do "what if" style scenarios on your model without persisting the change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how NHibernate sessions are DESIGNED to work.

If you'd rather do everything manually, use an `IStatelessSession` instead. You'll lose caching, lazy loading, etc.

Comment: Isn't there some way to accomplish this by toying with the flushmode as well?

Comment: Yes, you can set it to `Never` and it will only flush explicitly. But it's an all-or-nothing proposition: you can't selectively flush some entities.

Comment: Your second comment is what answered this for me.

Comment: @Alistair: Actually, I should hange my answer. The latest version of NHibernate introduces the `SetReadOnly` method in the session and the query, which prevents updating of that entity / group of entities.